# Apsidal Precession: What Am I Getting Wrong?

Tags: apsidal-precession

In *Precession of Mercury’s Perihelion from Ranging to the MESSENGER Spacecraft* (https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2017AJ....153..121P/abstract), one finds the precession of Mercury’s perihelion **due to the oblateness (quadrupole) of the Sun** to be:

$ \displaystyle \dot \varpi_{J_2} = \frac {3}{2} \frac {nJ_2}{(1-e^2)^2} \left( \frac {R_\odot}{a} \right)^2 \left(1 - \frac {3}{2} sin^2 i \right) $

(equation 3, p. 2). A few lines down, we read that it amounts to about 0.03″ per century—later refined to 0.0286″ per century.

However, when I do the calculation, with $ a $ = 57.90905 Gm, $ e $ = 0.20563, $ i $ = 3.38°, $ R_\odot $ = 696,342 km (all four from Wikipedia), $ n $ = 4.09°/d (calculated from formula 33.6 in Meeus 1998), and $ J_2 $ = 2.25 × 10⁻⁷ (paper’s abstract), I get 0.01855″ per century.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Plugging in those numbers, I got 0.02844" per century, which is roughly 1.53 times your value and fairly close to theirs, so I think the parameter values you chose are definitely right.

Comment: Can you please detail your calculation? Once you calculate $ \dot \varpi $, you need to convert to arcseconds per century; that might be where I screw up…

Comment: [Here's a Wolfram Alpha link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%283%2F2%29*%284.09+degrees+per+day%29*%282.25*10%5E%28-7%29%29+*+%281-%28.20563%29%5E2%29%5E%28-2%29+*+%28%28696%2C342+km%29%2F%2857.90905*10%5E9+meters%29%29%5E2+*+%281+-+%283%2F2%29*%28sin%283.38+degrees%29%29%5E2%29&assumption=%22UnitClash%22+-%3E+%7B%22degrees+per+day%22%2C+%7B%22AngularDegreesPerDay%22%7D%7D&assumption=%22ListOrNumber%22+-%3E+%7B%22Number%22%2C+%22696%2C342%22%7D) confirming the answer, although it's given in milliarcseconds per year.

Comment: Ha! That’s what I had wrong. The value obtained is in degrees per day (which I didn’t know); this is simply multiplied by 3600 to convert to seconds per day, then by 36525 to convert to seconds per century. Excellent. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

The value obtained is in degrees per day (which I didn’t know); this is simply multiplied by 3600 to convert to seconds per day, then by 36525 to convert to seconds per century.

Comment: The reason your answer came out in degrees per day is that you plugged in $n$ with those units.  Assuming you use the same units for both parts of the ratio Rsun/a, the only thing left that has units is $n$, so that will set the units of your answer.